# How to make a dropdown list like spinner Android but in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, spinner, xamarin.forms, dropdown, dropdownbox

I need your help !

I would like make a dropdown list in Xamarin Forms. I have a button in my xaml and when there is a click event, I would like that a list appear bottom this button. Look at pictures !

Thanks you in advance !

[List not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEixO.png)  /  [List visible and on foreground when image clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDAO2.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
yourlayout.xml
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click"
    android:id="@+id/click"/>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_below="@+id/click"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/list"/>
</RelativeLayout>

on your activity 
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
final Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click)
 click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            list.setVisibility(list.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that with this solution, listview don't appear on foreground. Moreover, I would like a solution to Xamarin forms (In the project PCL) if it's possible.